# Как правильно перейти с одной версии webpack на другую?

Tags: webpack

Сейчас в проекте используется webpack версии 1.9. Необходимо его обновить до 4.20. Проект использует слишком много зависимостей, могут возникнуть конфликты версий при апдейте. Поэтому такой вопрос, с чего начать апдейт, чтобы наступить на меньше граблей?

`.config.js`

```js
global.Promise = require('bluebird');

var webpack = require('webpack');
var zlib = require('zlib');
var path = require('path');
var utils = require('./utils');

var CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var TFStaticHashExport = require('./plugins/TFStaticHashExport');
var TFI18nPlugin = require('./plugins/TFI18nPlugin');
var TFRequireEnsureErrorPlugin = require('./plugins/TFRequireEnsureErrorPlugin');
var TFSourcemapUrlPlugin = require('./plugins/TFSourcemapUrlPlugin');

var PROJECT_ROOT = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../.././');
var NODE_MODULES = path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static/compilers/node_modules');
var BOWER_COMPONENTS = path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static/default/bower_components');
var STATIC_DIR = path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static/default/js');
var COMPILE_DIR = path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static/compile/default/js/');
var STATIC_FILES_HASHES = path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'config/static-files-hashes-webpack.php');
var LOCLIST_DIR = path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'loclists/compiled');

var COMPRESS_OPTIONS = {
  level: 9
};

// Пути и файлы которые будут подать в исключения парсеров
var NO_PARSE_NAME = [
  'clipboard.js',
  'traceur-runtime.js',
  path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/'),
  path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'CodeMirror/lib/'),
  path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'CodeMirror/mode/'),
  path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'CodeMirror/keymap/'),
  'JqueryDataTableWrapper',
  'jquery.dataTables.columnFilter',
  'jquery.multiselect',
  'jquery.multiselect.filter.min',
  'jquery.datetimepicker'
];

var WEBPACK_CACHE = {};
var TFSTATICK_HASH_EXPORT_CACHE = {};

module.exports = function(app, opts) {
  app = app || 'unknown';

  var filePrefix = utils.getFilePrefix(opts);
  var chunkPrefix = utils.getChunkPrefix(opts);
  var stylePrefix = utils.getFileStylePrefix(opts);

  var publicPath = '/compile/default/js/' + app + '/';

  if (opts.compressLevel) {
    COMPRESS_OPTIONS.level = opts.compressLevel;
  }

  // Тип sourcemap, зависимый от окружения
  var devtool = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev' ? 'eval' : 'source-map';

  return {
    name: app,

    cache: WEBPACK_CACHE,

    entry: {},

    output: {
      path: path.join(COMPILE_DIR, app),
      publicPath: publicPath,
      jsonpFunction: app + 'JSONP',
      filename: '[name]' + filePrefix + '.js',
      chunkFilename: '[name]' + chunkPrefix + '.chunk.js',
      sourceMapFilename: '[name]' + stylePrefix + '.map.js'
    },

    module: {
      loaders: [{
          test: /\.(less|css)$/,
          loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!autoprefixer!less?cleancss&sourceMap&ieCompat')
        },
        {
          test: /\.xml$/,
          loader: 'template'
        },
        {
          test: /browser\.json\.js/,
          loader: 'exports?JSON'
        },
        {
          test: /swfobject\.js/,
          loader: 'exports?swfobject'
        }
      ],

      noParse: NO_PARSE_NAME.map(function(name) {
        return new RegExp(name);
      })
    },

    externals: {},

    resolve: {
      root: [
        PROJECT_ROOT,
        NODE_MODULES,
        BOWER_COMPONENTS
      ],
      alias: {
        'jquery-ui': path.join(BOWER_COMPONENTS, 'jquery-ui/ui'),
        'jquery-migrate': path.join(BOWER_COMPONENTS, 'jquery-migrate/jquery-migrate'),
        underscore: path.join(BOWER_COMPONENTS, 'underscore/underscore'),
        masonry: path.join(BOWER_COMPONENTS, 'masonry/masonry'),
        clipboard: path.join(BOWER_COMPONENTS, 'clipboard/dist/clipboard'),
        bootstrap: path.join(BOWER_COMPONENTS, 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap'),
        swfobject: path.join(BOWER_COMPONENTS, 'swfobject/swfobject/swfobject'),
        SockJS: path.join(BOWER_COMPONENTS, 'sockjs/sockjs'),

        'jquery.event.clickoutside': path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/jquery.event.clickoutside.js'),
        'jquery.customControls': path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/jquery.customControls.js'),
        'jquery.datetimepicker': path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/jquery.datetimepicker.js'),
        'jquery.ui.datepicker-ru': path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/jquery.ui.datepicker-ru.min.js'), // may be unused
        'jquery.ui.touch-punch': path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js'),
        'jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom': path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js'),
        'jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom': path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js'),
        'jquery-ui-timepicker-addon': path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js'),
        'jquery-ui.datepicker.ru': path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/jquery-ui.datepicker.ru.js'),
        'chosen.jquery': path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/chosen.jquery.js'),
        'jquery.tokeninput': path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/jquery.tokeninput.js'),
        'custom-scrollbar': path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/custom-scrollbar.js'),
        'date-functions': path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/date-functions.js'),
        'jquery.cookie': path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/jquery.cookie.js'),
        'jquery.flot': path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/jquery.flot.js'),
        'jquery.jcrop': path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/jquery.jcrop.min.js'),
        'jquery.jstore': path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/jquery.jstore.js'), // may be unused
        'jquery.maskedinput': path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/jquery.maskedinput.js'),
        'jquery.mousewheel': path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/jquery.mousewheel.js'),
        'jquery.on.off': path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/jquery.on.off.js'),
        'jquery.pagination': path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/jquery.pagination.js'), // may be unused
        'jquery.placeholder': path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/jquery.placeholder.js'),
        'jquery.puzzle': path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/jquery.puzzle.js'), // may be unused
        'jquery.select': path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/jquery.select.js'),
        'jquery.sparkline': path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/jquery.sparkline.js'),
        'jquery.tablesorter': path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/jquery.tablesorter.min.js'), // is used in a template
        'jquery.tokenize': path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/jquery.tokenize.js'),
        'jquery.tools': path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/jquery.tools.min.js'),
        'jquery.tooltip': path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/jquery.tooltip.js'),
        'jquery.touch-events': path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/jquery.touch-events.js'),
        'jquery.tristate': path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/jquery.tristate.js'),
        'jquery-1.6.1': path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/jquery-1.6.1.js'), // is used in a template
        'jquery-1.6.2': path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/jquery-1.6.2.js'), // TODO replace with modern one
        excanvas: path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/excanvas.min.js'), // is used in a template
        detect: path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/detect.min.js'),
        howler: path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/howler.js'),
        Spinner: path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/spin.min.js'),
        json: path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/browser.json.js'),
        typeahead: path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/typeahead.js'),
        store: path.join(STATIC_DIR, 'lib/store.js'),
      }
    },

    resolveLoader: {
      root: [
        path.join(__dirname, 'loaders'),
        NODE_MODULES
      ],

      alias: {
        myStyle: 'style/url',
        myFile: 'file?name=[name]' + stylePrefix + '.css!less?strictMath&cleancss&sourceMap&ieCompat'
      }
    },

    plugins: [
      // В этом плагине можно указывать определения которые будут подставляться во время сборки
      // Что бы не было путаницы с константами в коде, пишем префикс "WPDEFINE"
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        WPDEFINE_APP_NAME: JSON.stringify(app)
      }),
      new TFRequireEnsureErrorPlugin({
        loadTimeout: 60 * 1000
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
      new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(true),
      new TFI18nPlugin({
        locales: opts.loclist,
        functionName: 'I18n.t',
        fileName: '{locale}' + chunkPrefix + '.js',
        failOnMissing: true,
        loclistDir: LOCLIST_DIR
      }),
      //new TFSourcemapUrlPlugin({
      //    staticDomain: opts.staticDomain,
      //    staticPath: publicPath
      //}),
      new CompressionPlugin({
        minRatio: 2,
        asset: '{file}.gz',
        algorithm: function(buffer, fn) {
          utils.zlibBuffer(zlib.Gzip(COMPRESS_OPTIONS), buffer, fn);
        }
      }),
      new TFStaticHashExport({
        filepath: STATIC_FILES_HASHES,
        hashlength: opts.hashLength,
        cache: TFSTATICK_HASH_EXPORT_CACHE,
        prefixRegexp: /_v([\w\d]+)/
      }),
      new webpack.ResolverPlugin(
        new webpack.ResolverPlugin.DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin('bower.json', ['main'])
      ),

      new ExtractTextPlugin('[name]' + filePrefix + '.css')
    ],

    stats: {
      children: false
    },

    devtool: devtool
  };
};

module.exports.LOCLIST_DIR = LOCLIST_DIR;
module.exports.NO_PARSE_NAME = NO_PARSE_NAME;
```

Comment: Не плохо бы увидеть `...config.js`, я, если честно, написал бы с нуля...

Comment: конфиг дать не могу, конфиденциальность :(

Comment: @Amandi конфиденциальность конфига? :D

Comment: @overthesanity ага, есть такое )

Comment: @overthesanity хотя сокращенную версию дать могу

Comment: Лично я просто начал бы писать новый конфиг с нуля по документации четвёртого вебпака, в старом конфиге лишь подглядыая требуемые фичи